# show alert while thread is sleep

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to show an alert while thread is sleeping
View is:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("generateDoc")',
    dataType: "json",
    mtype: "post",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#doc_generate").show();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#doc_generate").hide();
    }
});
```

Model is :

```
public Boolean docGenerate() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //Show $("#doc_generate") while thread sleeps and after 5 sec hide it
    return true;
}
```

Controller is:

```
public ActionResult generateDoc()
{
    Boolean isGenerated = gd.docGenerate();
    var data = new
    {
        isDocGen = isGenerated
    };
    return Json(data);
}
```

I didnot get appropriate result..It doesnot show alert..any suggestion?

Comment: what's the result you got?

Comment: @Nathan alert doesnot show..I want to show while thread sleep..and after `(5000)` alert must hide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971062/jquery-ajax-synchronous-call-beforesend)

Basically, beforesend is not firing if your call is synchronous. Nothing will happen unless the ajax call gets a response, much like an alert. An offered solution is to use an asynchronous call.